# Symfony EasyAdmin : update the actual NEW action crud with an extra function

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have actually a simple CRUD to my easyAdmin to create a new entity, I want to custom this new action by adding a function for sending an email after the entity created.

It is possible to custom the new action automatically created when I generated my crud with the symfony command ? or I have to create a new action custom with a function to create my entity and send the email ?

Answer (score 0):

hope my answer will be useful, there is a custom function in EasyAdmin is called "createEntity", something like that:

```
public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
{
    $activity = new Activity();
    $activity->setAccount($this->getUser());

    return $activity;
}
```

I think you can write the code you want above at it suits this function.